# 2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP etc

Tags: ios, cordova, audio

I created an iBeacon app to detect beacons using phonegap/cordova.  How the app works is that once it detects a nearby beacon and the app is closed or running in the background i use local notification which includes an audio (common apple notication sound).  I don't know why apple rejects it with the below comment:

> 2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.
>   Next Steps
>   The audio key is intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music player or streaming audio applications. Please revise your app to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>   Your app does not provide continuous streaming audio. For details on delivering an audible alert for a local notification, please refer to the About Local and Remote Notifications Programming Guide.
>   We hope you will consider making the necessary changes to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines and will resubmit your revised binary.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's comment is quite clear. Your app is incorrectly specifying that it needs the audio background mode. But it doesn't. That mode is only to be used to play audio (such as music) while the app is in the background. It is not to be used just to get audio from a local notification.

Remove the audio background mode setting from your app and Apple will be happy.

Comment: I don't remember specifying audio background, i wonder if the 3rd party plugin localnotification for phonegap automatically set that?  Can anyone help me on how to remove 'audio background mode' in phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

Even our App received a rejection last week for the same reason.

We didn't even need to submit a new binary. All we did was explained to the reviewer why we were using each of the background modes which we had listed in our plist. We did this by uploading a video in which we explained the purpose of each background mode. And then provided a link of this video in the resolution centre in iTunes connect. The reviewer had a look at it and later approved our app.

So you have to do a similar thing. If you need the background mode(audio in your case). Just explain it's intended purpose to the reviewer in the resolution centre. Else, just upload a new binary with the audio background mode removed from the plist.

Comment: We were using location and audio background modes for a native app. But irrespective of the the native/hybrid platforms you are using, you need to add the respective 'required background modes' to the .plist file of your ios build. These background modes are what apple verifies in the review.

Comment: Sorry i'm very confuse now, my app executes an audio when gets a local notification (this 3rd party local notification can set audio file) when the app is running in the background or it is closed.  This is what you call background mode?  So i just add that into the plist (is that property list) to clarify that this app uses background mode?

Comment: No. I presume that the fact that apple rejected your application, the audio background mode is already present in your iOS plist. By being present in your plist I mean that a value named 'background audio' is assigned against a key named 'required background modes' in your property list XML. You will need to remove this for Apple to approve it.

Comment: thanks for your help, i resumbitted it and it's approved.  strange, i asked phonegap forum they believe the xml config file i made a change too wasn't updated when i did a build online